# bash while within while

Tags: bash

I have a condition to test. I want variable A to equal Variable B. It might take a few tests in quick succession before A equals B. I don't want it to try more than 10 times, though.

```
A=1
B=2

while [ $A != $B ]
do
  echo "hi there"
done
```

So obviously that is just going to keep looping unless A ever equals B. Just in case A is not going to equal B anytime soon, I want to limit the number of tries. I was thinking of something like this:

```
A=1
B=2

COUNT=0
while [ "$COUNT" -le 10 ]
do
    while [ $A != $B ]
    do
      echo "hi there"
      COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`
    done

done
```

I found answers to similar questions here, but not quite this one.
Thanks!

Comment: What is modifying `A` and/or `B` that could make them equal?

Comment: Well, not that it matters much, but since you guys were so nice to help... I am rsyncing some data that is subject to change between the time the sync starts, and when it finishes. That's a bad thing. I need to make sure I get the whole thing intact, so I want two rsyncs in a row that show the same byte size. If I do this manually, I have to hit uparrow-return a few times real quick to get it intact. If I cant get it after 10 tries something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
A=1
B=2

COUNT=0
while [ "$COUNT" -le 10 ] || [ $A != $B ]
do
  echo "hi there"
  COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`
done
```

If I understand right you don't want to do too loops, but one loop with two breaking conditions.

Comment: That code does not seem to do it- loops forever. I need it to try a max of ten times to get A to equal B, and then maybe send me a warning email or something (need to decide on that). Of course, if I got A to equal B on the 4th try, or the 5th, etc., I want to stop at that point.

Comment: Still seems to loop, but I got another answer that works, thanks!

Comment: Replace || with && and it should stop after at most 11 loops (Set COUNT=1 to get 10 loops, or change -lt to -le - COUNT is being incremented after the test.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks William, I guess I was tired when I put an OR instead of an AND there :)

Comment: This works just as well for me as omaaj's answer (with the &&, that is), though his is a tad more concise. You guys are great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`while` (and many other compound commands) can be nested legally. Your logic isn't quite right for what you're trying to accomplish.

```
n=
while [[ $a != "$b" && ++n -le 10 ]]; do
    echo 'hi there'
done
```

For purely numeric comparisons, `[` and `[[` shouldn't be used in Bash.

```
for (( n = 0; a != b && ++n <= 10; )); do
    ...
```

There are many possibilities. As an aside, never use `expr` or backticks unless you require compatibility with ancient non-POSIX Bourne shells.

Comment: That was just beautiful. Now I need to see how it all works :)